# Using MVC Core Action Method, I want to pass JsonResult to the view. Data is retrieved from Models. What is the best way to do the same?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

***Method 1:***

Here data retrieved from database is converted to Json in Repository class and is passed to Controller

**Repository class method to retrieve data:**

```
public JsonResult GetEmployee(int Id)
        {
            Employee emp =  this._employeeList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == Id);
            return new JsonResult(emp);
        }
```

**Action Method in Controller:**

```
public ViewResult Details()
        {
            JsonResult model = _employeeRepository.GetEmployee(1);
            return View(model);
        }
```

***Method 2:***

Here data retrieved from database is converted to Json in Controller class at respective action Method

Repository class method to retrieve data:

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int Id)
        {
           return this._employeeList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == Id);

        }
```

**Action Method in Controller:**

```
public ViewResult Details()
        {
            Employee model = _employeeRepository.GetEmployee(1);
            return View(Json(model));
        }
```

**Which is the best method in terms of performance and other parameters?**

*P.s: I want to use the json data passed in View for Ajax scripts to display computed data*

Answer (score 0):

I would only render JSON into a view if I needed it to be part of a html response, in which case I'd serialise it as a string first, and pass it through as a property of my model.

If I also want to pass the same data via ajax, I would write a second function in my controller e.g. Details_ajax, which would return JsonResult and use return Json(data) to serialise the data.

In general, avoiding serialisation and deserialisation is most efficient where possible.